# panning position changes after modifying image fabricjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

i have a image that i am placing on the canvas at (0,0) then i call a function that places the image at a new point (0,100). One i do this the position of the image shift to the y=100 position and a strange behaviour is there- the bounding box (that controls the panning/scaling of the image) is shifted some pixel to the top of the image , once i click there the bounding box returns to the actual image position.

My jS code is as follows

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "car.png";
var canvas;
var imgInstance;

var imageDetails;
$(img).on('load', function () {
   canvas = new fabric.Canvas("imageCanvas");
   imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
      top: 0,
      left: 0
   });
   canvas.add(imgInstance);
   fullWidth();
});


function fullWidth() {
   var scaleRatio = canvas.width / imgInstance.width;
   imgInstance.scale(scaleRatio);
   console.log(scaleRatio);
   if (imgInstance.height < canvas.height) {
      console.log('canvas is bigger');
      imgInstance.set({top: 150});//((canvas.height- imgInstance.height)/2);
      //console.log(((canvas.height- imageDetails.height)/2));
   }
   ;
   canvas.renderAll();
   //canvas.calcOffset();
};
```

Comment: Got it , incase someone else facing similar problem - use             imgInstance.setCoords() before rendering to place the bounding box in the correct position.

Comment: you might want to add it as an answer and accept it. Don't think folks look in comments as much as they do the answers.